# Google Tag Manager Form Trigger

Tags: conversions, google-tag-manager, goal-tracking, tag-manager

I have Google Tag Manager installed on all pages. I want a specific tag to fire when the user fills out a form on `mysite.example/chanell1-theme`

The trigger I have set up now is:

1. Choose Event: `Form`
2. Configure Trigger: `Check validation, Wait for Tags`
3. Enable When: `url contains site.example/channel1`
4. Fire On: `All Forms`

Is that correct? If so, do I need to add anything to the actual page other than GTM itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be all you need. You just need to test it. Here's what I have for a form that includes validation (ie. error message appear if a required field is in error):

[image]